# Is the integral closure of a local domain in a finite extension of its field of fractions semi-local?

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Is the integral closure of a local domain in a finite extension of its field of fractions semi-local?

If the answer is negative, I wonder under what conditions it would be semi-local.

**EDIT**
Here's an example of a local domain which is not necessarily a Japanese ring.
Let $A$ be a valuation ring, $K$ its field of fractions.
Let $P$ be the maximal ideal of $A$.
Let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
It is well-known that there exist only finitely many valuation rings of $L$ dominating $A$.
Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $B$.
It is well-known that $M$ lies over $P$.
Hence $B_M$ dominates $A$.
There exists a valuation ring $R$ of $L$ dominating $B_M$.
Since $M$ is determined by $R$ and $R$ dominates $A$, there exist only finitely many maximal ideals of $B$.
Hence $B$ is a semilocal ring.

Note that $B$ is not necessarily a finite $A$-module(even if $A$ is a discrete valuation ring).
Hence $A$ is not necessarily a Japanese ring.

Comment: Semilocal here meaning that it has a finite number of maximal ideals?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some sufficient conditions:

Let $A$ be a local domain, $K$ its fraction field,  $L$ a finite extension of $K$, and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.  If $A$ is Noetherian and integrally closed, and $L$ is separable over $K$, then $B$ is necessarily finite over $A$, and so is semi-local (by going-up/down-type theorems).

If $A$ is not integrally closed, but its integral closure in $K$ is finite over itself, then again $B$ will be finite over $A$.

The condition that the integral closure of $A$ in $K$ be finite over $A$ is (at least by some people) called *N-1*.  More generally, the condition that $B$ be finite over $A$ is called *N-2*, or *Japanese*.  (The letter *N* here stands for *Nagata*, and I believe Grothendieck coined the adjecive *Japanese* for these rings because these properties were studied by Nagata and the commutative algebra school around him in Japan.)

So if $A$ is a Japanese ring, then $B$ will be finite over $A$, and hence semilocal.  Of course, this is rather tautological: its utility follows from the fact that many rings (indeed, in some sense, most rings --- i.e. most of the rings that come up in algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry) are Japanese.  E.g. all finitely generated algebras over a field, or over $\mathbb Z$, or over a complete local ring, are Japanese.

Here are some useful wikipedia entries related to this topic: [Nagata rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata_ring) and [Excellent rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-Noetherian result [Bourbaki, Commutative algebra, VI, $\S$8, no.3, Remarque]: For a valuation ring $R$ with fraction field $K$ and a finite field extension $L/K$, the integral closure of $R$ in $L$ is **semilocal**.